# Insert values into database from a web form using php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo

I have created a web form which validates each field and if every field is fill up and follows the requirements then it displays thank you message. Other wise it shows error.
What I am trying to do with the form is, I want to insert all the values into my database using PDO_MySql. I am referring a web link where you can find the codes. The reason why I didn't put on here is for my study issues.
<>https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6x9k3oo3t9zc3fz/OZtUYJAOKp<>

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what is is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code. You are not inserting anything in your database. 
You are just validating if the the required fields are present.

Comment: I know but I am not sure where I should put the pdo_mysql codes as I am a beginner user and I am taking help from a book. Please if you have some time and help me out sorting the problem then it will be very helpful..